# The meaning of the sentence "We don't all have to go down the line here"

Tags: meaning, verbs, idioms, american-english, translation

“**We don't all have to go down the line here**! I'm not playing around!“

The context of a cartoon situation is: a guy waving a fake gun (but everyone thinks tis real) yells at his hostage the following sentence, hoping they’re gonna believe the threat. 
What’s bothering me is the Russian translation, in which he says literally: **everybody’s gonna get a bullet in a head.**

I don’t really see the threat in English original version, like he says probably, “**not everyone gotta hurt**”, while in Russian there’s “**everybody’s getting a bullet**” :-D
I tried to find the meaning of a possible idiom here – “go down the line”, but only one dictionary gives it: “*To move from person to person or thing to thing, which are arranged in a line.*” WHICH isn’t a help here at all.

Please, could anybody help me with this sentence? What exactly did he mean. It’s bugging me for a few days. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The English and Russian versions seemingly say completely different things. In fact, they are partially the opposite of each other. Without knowing *what* he actually said, it's not possible to explain it.

Comment: If the cartoon is in English, and you can put a link to it, maybe it could be cleared up.